# How to check if ints are within a certain distance

Tags: integer, range

I feel like this is super simple, but its late and I feel really dumb right now
I'm making a simple program on Valorant ranks and which can play with each other.

I have two variables "rank" and "rank2"
rank = 1
rank2 = 6

how to check if rank is within x digits of rank2?

My brain is not working and i genuinely cant come up with anything to try

Answer (score 1):

you can check to see if some integer X is less than or equal to the absolute value of the difference. If X returns TRUE, then you know the ranks are within X digits.

adjust the syntax to your language of choice:

x <= (abs(rank - rank2))